# How to Iterate through MAP and send the Data to VFC Component to Send the Email to Case Owner

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have to send mail to Case Owner which is a queue with all the cases attach to it, in the email body. I have created Email Template and a VFC component. Code snippet is below:

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Action On Case" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
        <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
            Hi,<br/><br/>
            
            <c:ifb_caseprioritynotification /><br/><br/>
             
         </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="IFB_CasePriorityNotification">
    <table border="2" cellpadding="5">
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td><b>Case Number</b></td>
                 <td><b>Priority</b></td>
             </tr>
             <!--<apex:repeat var="caseExt" value="{!caseExtensionRecords}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!caseExt.IFB_Case__r.CaseNumber}</td>
                    <td>{!caseExt.IFB_Case__r.Priority}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>-->
          </tbody>
    </table>
</apex:component>
```

In apex class I have MAP of Queue and related List of records:

```
Map<String, List<SObject>> records
for (String key : records.keySet()) {
   List<SObject> records = castExtRecords.get(key);
}
```

For example : Queue1 : 10 Records
Queue 2 : 5 Records

How can I pass the List of record to VFC and use that in email Template.